# Firebase Storage await uploadTask.onComplete outdated

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Im using this code.
The error message is the following:
error: The getter 'onComplete' isn't defined for the type 'UploadTask'. (undefined_getter at [chatneu] lib/Screens/HomeScreen.dart:289)

```
  Future uploadFile() async {
    try {
      pr = new ProgressDialog(context);

      await ImagePicker().getImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery).then((image) {
        setState(() {
          _image = image as File;
          //klammern weg bei ImagePicker und .getImage zu Pickimage
        });
      });
      await pr.show();

      Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
          '${loggedInUser.uid}/UserProfille/${Path.basename(_image.path)}');
      UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);
      await uploadTask.onComplete;
      print('File Uploaded');
      storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
        setState(() {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(loggedInUser.uid);
          Map<String, String> data = {
            'photoUrl': fileURL,
          };
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that there is a method called `onComplete` on the UploadTask.  If you follow the example code in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#file-uploads), you will see that you just await the UploadTask directly:

```
await storageReference.putFile(_image);
storageReference.getDownloadURL().then(...);
```

You might also want to review the docs on [handling tasks](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#handling-tasks).

Comment: Just bumped here by following an apparently outdated Flutter tutorial for uploading Firebase images. FYI, there was a class before called `StorageUploadTask` that had `onComplete` method.

Comment: Useful answer but provided doc links are now dead. Updated link, for reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files

Answer (score 1):

onComplete does not have any more but there is different method is whenComplete may replace what you need.

```
await ref.putFile(image).whenComplete(() => doSomething());
```